# UIViewcontroller as a subview not getting touch events

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a UIViewController to another UIViewController and then have a UIGestureRecogniser on it. Is this a bad idea? I don't seem to receive touch events to the sub viewcontroller at all. Can I enable them or is this just a foolish practice?

CODE:

On main ViewController

```
let slider = SliderViewController()

slider.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height/4)

self.view.addSubview(slider.view)

slider.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // doesnt seem to make any difference
```

and on SliderViewController

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("touches began") // never gets called

}
```

If I present it with

```
self.present(slider, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

instead of adding as a subview, it works fine.

Comment: adding `UIViewController` inside `UIViewContoller` is not the way you want to develop for iOS. Use `UIView` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to add slider controller as a child controller too. By this way, UIKit will know that the view being added as a subview is tied to some view controller so it'll ensure that the child view controller will receive the same UI events such as user touches, orientation changes, lifecycle related callbacks like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` etc. as well.

To add `slider` as a child view controller, you should do:

```
self.addChildViewController(slider)
self.view.addSubview(slider.view)
slider.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

You should do the opposite in reverse order when removing the child view controller:

```
slider.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
slider.view.removeFromSuperView()
slider.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: This worked - self.addChildViewController(slider) is the line that makes the difference. slider.didMoveToParentViewController(self) doesn't have any affect. Will accept your answer in one minute when it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: You should still call `didMoveToParentViewController` though. Because it causes the child view controller to be notified about being added as a child view controller via some callbacks you probably don't need so didn't implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
slider.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

after

```
self.view.addSubview(slider.view)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - no difference though :(